# How to set full width and height for chrome new window

Tags: google-chrome-app

How can I create new window with full of available space in display screen.

```
function CreateWindow () {
    chrome.app.window.create("Spreadsheet.html" , {
        "bounds"    :   {
            "width" :   500,          // need full width and height
            "height":   400 
        }
    });
}

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(CreateWindow);
```

Comment: please re-evaluate the answer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access window.innerWidth and height though you can use below code

```
function CreateWindow () {
    chrome.app.window.create("Spreadsheet.html" , {
        "bounds"    :   {
            "width" :   window.screen.availWidth,
            "height":   window.screen.availHeight   
        }       
    });
}

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(CreateWindow);
```

Answer (score 7):

Create the window maximized to use all available screen space.

```
chrome.app.window.create("Spreadsheet.html" , { state: 'maximized'}
```

See [app window documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html) for more details.