# Create window at bottom of screen

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am able to create a new window with my app, but I was wondering if there was a way for this window to open at the bottom of the screen.  The preferred behavior would be, given a height, fill in a window from the left to right side of the screen and be all the way at the bottom of that screen.  Like a bottom-docked panel.

Is there some attribute I can add to the create to make this happen?  All I can think is to set left to 0, but that only solves one thing.

```
chrome.app.window.create("window.html", {
  alwaysOnTop: true,
  id: "info_view",
  bounds: {width:600, height:400},
});
```

The app window create reference is here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-CreateWindowOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, It looks like `bounds` is deprecated; you should use `innerBounds` or `outerBounds` instead.

Second, all of the bounds take a [`BoundsSpecification`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-BoundsSpecification) which has arguments for `left` and `top`.  You can get the screen display bounds using [`chrome.system.display.getInfo(function callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display#method-getInfo) which returns a `workArea` (and a `bounds`, depending on your intent).

Then, probably you want to pass to `window.create` something like

```
outerBounds: {
  top: screenInfo.workArea.height - window_height,
  height: window_height
}
```

(Note: I haven't tried it, yet)

Comment: I got getInfo working ([systemInfo Example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/systemInfo))

However, bounds nor outerBounds work.  When giving properties to bounds, nothing happens the the window will open where it last closed.  Perhaps because it is deprecated.

With outerbounds, it gives me an error.  Perhaps because it is not supported until Chrome 36 and I am running Chrome 34.  I don't know how I'd get this to work since the highest beta version I can find is 35.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Chrome debugger error messages yet, but this is what it gave me:    
`Error in response to system.display.getInfo: Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property 'outerBounds': Unexpected property.`

Comment: I may have been hasty with my suggestion of `bounds` as deprecated; its only been recently marked as such.

Comment: `chrome.system.display.getInfo` accepts a callback that accepts an object.  I think you should do something like `chrome.system.display.getInfo(function(info){ console.log(info[0].workArea); });`

Comment: Seems getInfo returns an array of screens, marked with `isPrimary` `isEnabled` etc.  For an initial experiment, using the first array element is fine, but you should add support for multi-monitor.

Comment: Also: workArea has a `top` value which you will want to add to your `window.create` `top`.  If only we supported `bottom` :)

Comment: If you pass an id to your window it will use the remembered position of the window, no matter what you pass in via bounds or one of the newer variants.

Comment: Yes, my problem with bounds was that it will always go to the last known if the id is set.
Removing that, I got width and height to work. (FYI `width: window.screen.availWidth` is equivalent to `width: screenInfo.workArea.width` in this instance [(source)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18912217/3617788))
However, the `top` and `left` properties only work when both of them are set. A bit silly, but it works now. Thanks!